# react render method invalid syntax error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have index.js like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Login from './containers/Login'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

const store = configureStore()

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Login />
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

when I build this with `npm run build` it gives me syntax error. 
What might be wrong in here ?

Comment: Could you add the syntax error?

Comment: render(
> 10 |    <Provider store={store}>
     |    ^
  11 |      <Login />
  12 |   </Provider>,
  13 |   document.getElementById('root')

Comment: Looks like it doesn't know how to process JSX. Are you sure you really transpile your JSX in your index.js?

Comment: I dont think I am using jsx

Answer (score 1):

You are using JSX, so you must transpile them (I would suggest using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which can transpile both JSX and ES6).

Otherwise, you could go without JSX using this

```
render(
  React.createElement(Provider, {store: store},
    React.createElement(Login, {})
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```